# Join 2 DataFrames on an index without introducing nans on missing indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 DataFrames:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=['a','b','c'])
df2 = df1*2
df2.index = [1,2,3]

>>> df1
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

>>> df2
    a   b   c
1   2   4   6
2   8  10  12
3  14  16  18
```

Say I want to add the `a` column from `df2` to `df1` based on index:

```
df1['a'] += df2['a']
>>> df1
    a  b  c
0 NaN  2  3
1   6  5  6
2  15  8  9
```

This works fine when the index is present in both frames, but I would like to just add zero in the case where an index is missing, rather than introduce `nan`s. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You mean something like, `df['a'] = (df1['a'] + df2['a']).fillna(0)`?

Comment: @JohnGalt that could work but if df['a'] was nonzero to begin with then this would give the wrong answer.

Comment: Then `df1['a'] + df2['a'].reindex(df1.index).fillna(0)` reindex() should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Series.add` with the argument `fill_value=0`:

```
>>> df1['a'] = df1['a'].add(df2['a'], fill_value=0)

>>> df1
    a  b  c
0   1  2  3
1   6  5  6
2  15  8  9
```